# Yii2 how to set the title for the widget ListView

Tags: php, yii2, yii-widgets

I have installed in Yii 1.1

```
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
'template' => Yii::t('Site','Header News')
```

But how 'to do it in Yii2 ?

```
echo ListView::widget(['template' => Yii::t('Site','Header News'), 
    'dataProvider' => $tipsList,
    'itemView' => '_listItem',
    'layout' => '{items}{pager}',
    'itemOptions' => [
    ],
    'options' => [
        'links' => '<h2>test</h2>',
        'tag' => 'ul',
        'class' => 'ten-vertical summary-list',

    ],

    'viewParams' => array(
        'categoryAlias' => $categories[0]->urlAlias,
        'imageConfig' => array('width' => 120, 'height' => 120, 'fill' => true),
        'firstImageConfig' => array('width' => 436, 'height' => 436, 'fill' => true),
    ),
]);
```

Param `'template' => Yii::t('Site','Header News')` does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`template` property of ListView in Yii2 called `layout`. [Link](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/widgets/BaseListView.php)

Comment: How to use it? Give some examples.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
'layout' => '<li class="list-header">Header</li>{items}{pager}',
'options' => [
        'tag' => 'ul',
],
```

The **li.list-header** will be added into a parent tag **ul**